# When to use app.get("/",fun(res,req)) and app.post("/",fun(res,req)) in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I am confused between `app.get()` and `app.post()`. Also when to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the HTTP protocol, we use different URLs to retrieve, add, update or delete information.
To specify which action we want to perform we add to the URL the HTTP method (also called as HTTP verb).

2 popular HTTP verbs are:

- GET - indicate we want to retrieve / get information (e.g. get information about a user).
- POST - indicate we want to post / add new information (e.g. add a new user).

**In ExpressJS framework** we register a handler function (known as a middleware) for each possible route that our app should handle.

to register a handler function to a route that uses the **GET** method, we use:

```
.get(<route>, <middleware>)
```

and to register a handler function to a route that uses the **POST** method, we use:

```
.post(<route>, <middleware>)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Hi, in API we use

---

1. **GET** to get data
2. **POST** to add data
3. **PUT** to edit data
4. **PATCH** to edit data
5. **DELETE** to delete data

Comment: to get data from where?

Comment: from API like if you need data about users you can make get req
to "/users/"

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Kareem Adel and @Idan Krupnik, that is their uses but their usage is also dependent on how good you are to implement them. A GET method can still be used for POST method so also DELETE PUT and PATCH, using the HTTPS verbs for their intended is just to make our codes readable and more presentable for future references and your peers. We are just following syntaxes, which is good. My point is to not be confused with how they are, just stick to the rules but know that rules are there to be violated, so, you shouldn't be surprised if you see in another person's code calling GET method while POST is being implemented in the callback function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).